# Read XML with C# and fill List<T>

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document that contains data about two table.
The structure is like this

```
<doc>
  <table name="ordini">
    <row>
      <field name="id">0431524493258932</field>
      <field name="anno">2018</field>
      <field name="att">0000</field>
      <field name="cen">01</field>
      ...
    </row>  
    <row>
      <field name="id">1041524493596749</field>
      <field name="anno">2018</field>
      <field name="att">0000</field>
      <field name="cen">01</field>
      ...
    </row>
...

</table>
 <table name="righe">
    <row>
      <field name="id">0431524493258932</field>
      <field name="anno">2018</field>
      <field name="att">0000</field>
      <field name="cen">4U</field>
....

</table>
<doc>
```

I am trying this way with first table in XML with a lot of confusion

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

var ordcli = doc.Descendants("table")
             .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("name") == "ordini")
             .Descendants("row")
             .Select(e => e.Elements());

foreach (var item in ordcli)
{
    foreach (var i in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

How can I read every row element and get field name to instantiate my `Order` class and `OrderDetails` class?

When I have my `List<Order>` and `List<OrderDetails>` filled I can populate relative tables.
I hope I've explained my requirement well.
I've never used XlmReader or Linq2Xml. It's first time.

Comment: Check for `SelectMany`

Comment: You might want to research XML serialization/deserilization. If your XML structure maps your class structure then you can simply _deserialize_ into a collection of your class. Otherwise you can continue down the path you’re on and instantiate a new Order object in your Linq Select() statement (and map the properties from the XML).

Comment: Use following for your write statement : Console.WriteLine("Name = '{0}', Value = '{1}'", (string)i.Attribute("name"), (string)i);

Answer (score 0):

try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new XML_DataSet(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class XML_DataSet
    {
        static DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        public XML_DataSet(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

            foreach(XElement table in doc.Descendants("table"))
            {
                ds.Tables.Add(ReadTable(table));
            }

        }

        private DataTable ReadTable(XElement table)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Boolean first = true;

            foreach (XElement xRow in table.Elements("row"))
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    foreach (XElement field in xRow.Elements("field"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add((string)field.Attribute("name"), typeof(string));
                    }
                    first = false;
                }
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                foreach (XElement field in xRow.Elements("field"))
                {
                    newRow[(string)field.Attribute("name")] = (string)field;
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not try your code... is too sofisticated for me...
I try  switch ((string)field.Attribute("name")) inside the inner foreach. What you think?

Comment: I prefer using DataSet/DataTable because you have both the name and the value in one object.  I also have a multiple tables.  Your solution is more complicated because you do not have an association between name and value and you do not have a method to seperate tables into different objects.